# Asymptotic of a sequence related to $LCM(1,\cdots,n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $d_n=LCM(1,2,\cdots, n)$ and $u_n$ be a sequence such that $u_n=o(d_n)$. Some testing in maple suggests the following asymptotic:

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\log(\sum_{k=0}^n(d_k+u_k)\binom{n}k)}{n}=\log(1+e)$$

Unfortunately, I did not manage to prove it. Any hints would be welcome to answer this question. I know that $d_n=e^{n+o(n)}$.

Comment: But where is $u_n$ used in the formula?

Comment: there is some information about $d_n$ here: http://oeis.org/A003418

Comment: My bad! I edited my post.

Comment: Is it easy when $u_k$ is the zero sequence?

Comment: As far as I can see, this follows in a straightforward way from $d_n=e^{n+o(n)}$. For a given $\epsilon>0$, fix $c$ such that $d_n+u_n\le e^{(1+\epsilon)n}$ for $n\ge c$; then the sum is bounded by $(e^{1+\epsilon}+1)^n+O(n^c)$, etc. The lower bound is similar.

Comment: This is the prime number theorem